# Eloquent whereBetween query is being ignored

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I need to get a Users' Booking between two dates. But when I run the Eloquent query, it brings back bookings that are not between the two given dates. I think it might be down to how the query is ran as priority? However thought I'd ask.

So for context

- User HasMany Bookings
- Bookings (Date) is a date column in my database
- Date range is from 07-07-2022 to 07-21-2022

The ran query for my database is :

```
select * from `users` 
where exists 
(select * from `bookings` 
where `users`.`id` = `bookings`.`user_id` 
and DATE(bookings.date) 
between '2022-07-07' 
and '2022-07-21' 
and `bookings`.`deleted_at` is null order by `date` asc) 
and `users`.`deleted_at` is null
```

My Eloquent is as follows :

```
$users = User::whereHas('bookings', function($q) use ($start, $end)
        {
            $q->whereBetween(\DB::raw('DATE(bookings.date)'), [$start, $end]);
        })->get();
```

This is a debug of the result of this code, As you can see there's some dates outside of my needed range.

[image: Result]

I am using Laravel 5.8

Comment: How/where are loading the actual bookings? At the minute, your query is only looking for users that have bookings between those dates, you're not constraining the bookings themselves.

Comment: Hi @Rwd not too sure what you're asking here. The Bookings are coming in from the Booking Model with a date column. But the query is not filtering out the dates despite me asking for it to do so?

Comment: currently, your query is retrieving the users that have bookings between those dates, it's not filtering the booking so what you can do is filter out the bookings first and then retrieve their user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's get into the difference between whereHas and with

**Where**

This method allows you to [query based on relationship existence](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence). This is like saying.

pseudo code

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE HAS BOOKS THAT HAVE DATE BETWEEN ? and ?
```

**with**

This method gives you the ability to load in data from a relationship and gives you the ability to constrain the received data. see >> [Constraining Eager Loads](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads)

pseudo code

```
SELECT * from users AND also select * from books where date between ? and ?
```

In your case, you can combine them and do something like:

```
User::whereHas('books', function ($query) {
    $query->whereDateBetween('date', [$from, $till]);
})->with(['books' => function ($query) {
    $query->whereDateBetween('date', [$from, $till]);
}])
```

^^ This gives you only users who have books between those dates and gives you a collection instance of books on the user with the correct data

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Laravel last version but when see the documentation of version 5.8, can't find `whereBetween` then use simple `where` in your query, may work:

```
$users = User::whereHas('bookings', function($q) use ($start, $end) {
        $q->where('bookings.date', '>=', $start)->where('bookings.date', '<=',  $end);
})->get();
```

or

```
$users = User::whereHas('bookings', function($q) use ($start, $end) {
        $q->where(\DB::raw('DATE(bookings.date)'), '>=', $start)->where(\DB::raw('DATE(bookings.date)'), '<=', $end);
})->get();
```